# Retrieve {BinderCategory} field value using Lotus Notes Formula Language

Tags: migration, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I'm using the Dell Migrator tool in migrating Lotus Notes to Sharepoint. One of the challenges that has me stumped, is getting the value from the {BinderCategory} field.

I have tried using:

- @GetField("BinderCategory")
- @GetDocField("BinderCategory")
- @Text(@BinderCategory)

But all of them return null values.

Any ideas guys?

P.S. I also tried using @GetField("DDSCategory1") and @GetField("DDSCategory2"), but they return different values.

Comment: @Text(@BinderCategory) should be a syntax error. If it's not, then there's something very unusual about the environment of the Dell Migrator tool that you're not telling us about.

Answer (score 0):

If the formula runs in the context of the document which contains the field "BinderCategory" then you write just

```
BinderCategory
```

to get the content of this field.

Example:

Field "BinderCategory" contains the value "Administrator". The formula

```
"Category: " + BinderCategory
```

returns "Category: Administrator"